# Html.Action passing value from model returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I'm trying to pass a value into an Html.Action using FirstOrDefault to return the first entry in an array of values. The value is not picked up and I keep getting a null exception.

The `family` variable picks up the correct values from the model as a key/value pair.

What do I need to do to pass the zero indexed Value "2" as the parameter in the Action?

**Code and debug information:**

[image: VisualStudio]

----Edit for Code---

**Family Index Action**

```
    public ActionResult Index(int familyId)
    {            
        var model = GetDisplay(familyId).OrderByDescending(i => i.dob);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

**Family ViewModel**

```
public partial class FamilyListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int familyId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: We can't see your code.

Comment: Looking at that, why don't you just pass `family` since it's already a RouteValueDictionary which is what one of the overloads of `Action()` expects?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I've added the ViewModel and the Index action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a Dictionnary, you have to retrieve the value of your key like this :

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Family", new { familyId = family["Id"] })
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: this still returns null

Comment: family["Id"] returns null ?

Comment: this still returns null, yes.

Comment: The Action is looking for `familyId`, not `id`.

Comment: Good spot Jim - can't see the wood for the trees sometimes. The above works now Joffrey, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code and send the `familyId` parameter as expected by your action

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Family", new{familyId= Model.familyId })
```

Comment: this still returns null